# Using ng-grid with a filter to insert html

Tags: angularjs, cell, ng-grid

I am new to Angular, and have started working with the ng-grid.  I am able to display my data in the grid ok, but one of my columns has data that *can* be multi-line.  To allow for this, I added a filter called via a template to insert `<br>` between the values, if it is multi-line. Unfortunately, this displays the data as: "value1`<br>`value2". I think I can use $sce.trustAsHtml in my filter to return the needed html, but I'm not quite sure how to call my filter and receive the results in my html, since I *think* I need to put the safe html in a ng-bind-html directive.  How is might this be done?  I think I'm not understanding how the filter gets called from my html.

Or is there a better way to display multi-line results in a single cell?

Here's my filter below. I've cut out a lot of business logic to keep it concise, and omitted the ngrid columnDefs which has my setup for the cellTemplate):

```
.filter('valueDisplay', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(dataArray) {
    var domEls = "";
    if (dataArray)
        domEls = dataArray[0].value + '<br>' + dataArray[1].value;
    return domEls; // - that returns 'value1<br>value2'
    // return $sce.trustAsHtml(domEls); does not work - it displays as ""
  };
}])
```

And my html cellTemplate:

```
<div ng-style="{'cursor': row.cursor}" data>
<div ng-class="'ngCellText colt' + $index" class="ngCellText cellToolTip">
    {{row.getProperty(col.field) | valueDisplay}}</div>
</div>
```